# unable to launch FireFox custom profile with geckodriver in java

Tags: java, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to launch a Firefox profile with add-ons in it, with selenium v3.12 and gecko-driver v2.10 and Firefox version 60.0, how-ever it seems that the custom profile is not working. below is my code

```
static WebDriver driver;
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        myprofile = profile.getProfile("AutoProfile");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
  "E:\\Library\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

the acutal error is on the line

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

as

> The constructor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxProfile) is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it through firefox options.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Library\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("AutoProfile");
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(myprofile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

If the below solution causes a java heap error, you could try DesiredCapabilities, like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Library\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
File file = new File(path_to_your_firefox_profile);
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(file);
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Comment: Seems to be working but now getting an exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.asString(JsonOutput.java:282)
 at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$2(JsonOutput.java:110)at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$51/11830049.consume(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you check your Firefox profile size? try to clear your cache before, and try again.

Comment: No not sure of it,how to deal this problem

Comment: Added another approach, please test @Prasad_Joshi